# Querying XElement using Linq - getting XElement deep down

Tags: c#, .net, linq, xpath, linq-to-xml

I have a XML document like shown below:

```
<root>
  <level1>
    <level2>
      <level3>
       .....
      </level3>
      <level3>
       .....
      </level3>

    </level2>
  </level1>
</root>
```

I want to select all level3 elements, in `XPath` i would do `root/level1/level2/level3` but how do i do it using `LINQ`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var elements = document.Descendants("level3").ToList();
```

or if you need to follow exact path

```
var elements = document.Element("root").Element("level1").Element("level2").Elements("level3").ToList();
```

or XPath, but still will `XDocument`

```
var elements = document.XPathSelectElements("root/level1/level2/level3").ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use .Decendants

[An example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/XML-LINQ/QueryXMLwithDescendants.htm)